How to locate crash reason in Xcode?
Here is the crash stack

Here is the true reason of the crash

[ViewController click] is not showing in the crash stack, I found a solution is adding a Exception Breakpoint, but is there another way to locate crash line in stack?

Add the error message in your question, which will help find the cause.
